# keep getting DiscordAPIError: Unknown Interaction when using reconlx's pagination for my queue command on my music bot in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, npm, pagination, discord, discord.js

So I have a music bot written using `discord.js` and I have decided to use pagination for my queue command so that I can display the whole queue neatly. However, I keep getting the Unknown interaction discord API error *most* of the time I click on a button to switch pages. I am using the `reconlx npm package` and here is my code for the queue command:

```
            const queue = distube.getQueue(message)

        // embeds
        const nothingPlaying = new MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription('Nothing playing right now!');

        if(!queue) return message.channel.send({ embeds: [nothingPlaying]} );

        const queueEmbed1 = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Current Queue:')
        .setDescription(`${queue.songs
                            .map(
                                (song, id) =>
                                    `**${id ? id : 'Playing'}**. ${song.name} - \`${
                                        song.formattedDuration
                                    }\``,
                        )
                        .slice(0, 20)
                        .join('\n')}`
                    )
        const queueEmbed2 = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Current Queue:')
        .setDescription(`${queue.songs
                            .map(
                                (song, id) =>
                                    `**${id ? id : 'Playing'}**. ${song.name} - \`${
                                        song.formattedDuration
                                    }\``,
                        )
                        .slice(20, 40)
                        .join('\n')}`
                    )
        const queueEmbed3 = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Current Queue:')
        .setDescription(`${queue.songs
                            .map(
                                (song, id) =>
                                    `**${id ? id : 'Playing'}**. ${song.name} - \`${
                                        song.formattedDuration
                                    }\``,
                        )
                        .slice(40, 60)
                        .join('\n')}`
                    )
        const queueEmbed4 = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Current Queue:')
        .setDescription(`${queue.songs
                            .map(
                                (song, id) =>
                                    `**${id ? id : 'Playing'}**. ${song.name} - \`${
                                        song.formattedDuration
                                    }\``,
                        )
                        .slice(60, 80)
                        .join('\n')}`
                    )
        const queueEmbed5 = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Current Queue:')
        .setDescription(`${queue.songs
                            .map(
                                (song, id) =>
                                    `**${id ? id : 'Playing'}**. ${song.name} - \`${
                                        song.formattedDuration
                                    }\``,
                        )
                        .slice(80, 100)
                        .join('\n')}`
                    )
                    


        const embeds = [
            queueEmbed1,
            queueEmbed2,
            queueEmbed3,
            queueEmbed4,
            queueEmbed5,
        ]

        
        pagination({
            embeds: embeds,
            channel: message.channel,
            author:message.author,
            fastSkip: true,    
        })
```

The slice(**NUMBERS**) are the song positions that are shown and therefore I have set a new embed for each page, I know it's a mess but I couldn't think of a way to make it neater as I am not that familiar with programming yet. Thanks for any help I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

pagination is used more on websites or developper web pages, trying to use it on a bot is possible but way harder and complex. I suggest you use [`discord-slider`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-slider). It is way more simple to use and handle better prolbems facing the discord api in your case. You can use it like so :

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()


require("discord-buttons")(client);
require('discord-slider')(client);

// On a command :

channel.createSlider(userID, embedsArray, emojiNext, emojiBack)
```

In your case for example, you can use

```js
channel.createSlider(message.author.id,embeds, "Next", "Back")
```

Learn more [`here`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-slider)

--

**PS** : You seem to repetitively create the same embed with just a little bit of change. Try creating a loop, trust me it's way more efficient and you can even choose how many embeds you would want by just changing the `5` on the 3rd line !

```js
let embeds = []

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
 embeds.push(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Current Queue:')
        .setDescription(queue.songs
                            .map(
                                (song, id) =>
                                    `**${id ? id : 'Playing'}**. ${song.name} - \`${
                                        song.formattedDuration
                                    }\``,
                        )
                        .slice((i*20), (i+1)*20)
                        .join('\n')
                    ))
}
```